# Database is not created in sqlite

Tags: android

There is two database is already in my project and want to create a new database for some task
but database is not created i think i am doing something wrong in my code please help me out this problem.
Thanks.

```
public class LikeShareDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    static final int version = 10;
    static final String dbName = "LikeShareDB";
    static final String LikeAndShare = "LikeAndShareTable";
    static final String coluId = "id";
    static final String coluTask = "Task_id";
    static final String coluLike = "TLike";
    static final String coluComment = "TComment";
    static final String coluTSahre = "Tshare";
    static final String coluMySelf = "mtself";

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + LikeAndShare + " (" + coluId
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + coluTask + " TEXT, "
            + coluLike + " TEXT, " + coluComment + " TEXT, " + coluTSahre
            + " Text, " + coluMySelf + " TEXT );";

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    private LikeShareDbHelper dbHelper;

    public LikeShareDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, dbName, null, version);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + LikeAndShare);
        onCreate(db);

    }


    public LikeShareDbHelper open() throws SQLException {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        // dbHelper.open();
        return this;
    }

    // ---closes the database---
    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }


}
```

Comment: @deep-u have given permisson in android mainfest.xml file for external storage.

Comment: yes i have given permission in menifest.xml

Comment: @deep-i have added my code i have sucessfully created database u just created like this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this ..more helpful for u

package com.databases;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    Context mContext;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Personal_Assistant_Chronical.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_DETAIL = "newContact";

    private static final String COLUMN_PERSON_ID= "personID";
    private static final String COLUMN_PERSON_NAME= "person_name";
    private static final String COLUMN_MOBILE_NUMBER = "mobile_no";
    private static final String COLUMN_LANDLINE_NUMBER = "lanline_no";
    private static final String COLUMN_FAX_NUMBER = "fax_no";
    private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL_ID = "email_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_PERSONAL_ADDRESS = "personal_address";
    private static final String COLUMN_WORK_ADDRESS = "work_address";

    private static final String CREATE_DETAIL_TABLE = "create table if not exists "
            + TABLE_DETAIL
            + "("
            + COLUMN_PERSON_ID
            +" INTEGER primary key autoincrement, "
            + COLUMN_PERSON_NAME
            + " VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE, "
            + COLUMN_MOBILE_NUMBER
            + " VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , "
            + COLUMN_LANDLINE_NUMBER
            + " VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_FAX_NUMBER
            + " VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_EMAIL_ID
            + " VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_PERSONAL_ADDRESS
            + " VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_WORK_ADDRESS
            + " VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL); "
            ;
    private static final String TABLE_PERSONAL = "newPersonal";

    private static final String COLUMN_DATE_ID= "dateID";
    private static final String COLUMN_DATE= "fate";
    private static final String COLUMN_DIARY= "diary";

    private static final String CREATE_PERSONAL_TABLE = "create table if not exists "
            + TABLE_PERSONAL
            + "("
            + COLUMN_DATE_ID
            +" INTEGER primary key autoincrement , "
            + COLUMN_DATE
            +" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE, "
            + COLUMN_DIARY
            + " VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL); "

            ;   


    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.mContext=context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_DETAIL_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_PERSONAL_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        if (db != null)
            onCreate(db);
    }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate a bit more your problem. You said "I think" to tell us the database is not created. What did you check to be 100% sure about that?

Also, do not use "id" but "_id". It is already defined for you by `BaseColumns._ID`.

Comment: Ok just curious about what you did to check the database is not there. Did you try to write something an got an error?
Did you try changing id to _id?

Comment: ya i write _id instead of id and i am checking in ddms->data->project package name. there two old database is there but new which i am creating is not there.

Comment: @deep-just delete your both database by command promt and created again new database

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + LikeAndShare + " (" + coluId
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + coluTask + " TEXT, "
            + coluLike + " TEXT, " + coluComment + " TEXT, " + coluTSahre
            + " Text, " + coluMySelf + " TEXT )";
```

Replace this code with your code. Hope its work.

Comment: Or you can take help from this link.  http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Database onCreate method is called when the database is opened via getWritableDatabase....try doing it.